# Can't Install eclipse theme

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have recently switched Eclipse workbench and installed *again* the MoonRise UI Theme for my Eclipse.
Unfortunately I don't know why font colors don't change. Can anyone help me?

Running Eclipse Mars
How it should be:
[image]

How it is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have got the answer by now.

To get the fonts one must change the preference. There is an existing preference available by name `RainbowDrops.epf`. You can import the same to get a dark theme look.

A complete tutorial along with the `RainbowDrops.epf` file is available in the below link.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme/metrics

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a theme problem but you need to maven update , refresh and mvn clean install your project.
These steps fixed my problem.